# How to append in head of file and remove something in the end of file

Tags: ruby

Can I achieve this without lopping through each line in the file,

I'd rather it can be done by `inject`, but I have no idea how to ?

suppose my file's format is

```
{},
{},
...
{},
```

I want it be that way like a Json format, appending `[ ]` and remove a `,` in the end

```
[
{},
{},
...
{}
]
```

Comment: Hi, `inject` is an **Enumerable** method, which will always do iterate.

I think you may `File.read` the entire content as a string, and then work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to just read the whole file into memory, if you have enough memory.

```
original = File.read(filename).strip
File.write(filename, "[\n" + original[0..-2] + "\n]\n")
```